# How to set min-height to div which is in another div in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter-Bootstrap and have set the `min-height: 100%` for the div class `main`. However, I'm not able to set the `min-height: 70%` for another div class `sub`.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="main col-xs-12">
    <div class="sub col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.main
{
    min-height : 100%;
    border : 2px solid #000000;
}
.sub
{
    min-height : 70%;
    border : 2px solid #fffffff;
}
```

Comment: you have marked the answer which is the exact duplicate of mine..!!

Comment: this is what you will be getting if you have don't have content in teh div http://jsfiddle.net/rzFk9/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
 <div class="main col-xs-12">
     <div class="sub col-xs-6"></div>
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html
{
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
.main
   {
       height:100%;
    min-height : 100%;
    border : 2px solid #000000;
   }
   .sub
   {
    min-height : 70%;
    border : 2px solid red;
   }
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nM4G7/)

## [Full Page Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nM4G7/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

Nesting min-height & height or both does not works in css, since height is required to detect min-height & vice verca. Use `height:100%` in your code instead of min-height. And also give height:100% to html & body.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ayazshah/rzFk9/)**

```
.main
       {
           height:100%;
        min-height:100%;
        border : 2px solid #000000;
        position:absolute;
       }
       .sub
       {
        min-height : 70%;
        border : 2px solid #ff0000;

       }

    <div class="main col-xs-12">
         <div class="sub col-xs-6">ABCD</div>
       </div>
```

Comment: No sir I'm front end developer with three year experience. It's mine code I don't copy the codes.